# Is it possible to play the "Earth" map in mulitplayer?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I'm playing Sid Meier's Civilization V: Gods & Kings in multiplayer mode over local network with my wife. It's all great, but I can't find a way to choose "Earth". Does anyone know how to do so, or if its even possible?

Answer (score 5):

There is no earth map in MP, sadly.